# calling greatest least Postgresql functions dynamically

Tags: postgresql

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_least(VARIADIC list numeric[])
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
if <some condition>
    return least(list );
END; $function$
```

Userdefined variable param functions has construct `VARIADIC  array` and passing values as array but built in function `greatest` and `least` are not taking this array list as input ?
how to call them dynamically. I don't want make csv list and call using execute .

I know we can result by min equal to least by non scallar means. i.e by
traversing by `generate_subscripts()` function.
My question is is there any way I call least or greatest in functions dynamically ?

Comment: this is not duplicate , i am not asking how to min of array , I asking how to call geatest or least functions dynamically.